# JVM bytecode question when use `System.out.println`

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

here is an example of https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-class-file-constant-pool

```
class Hello {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            System.out.println( "Hello from Hello.main!" );
  }
}
```

bytecode as below

```
 0: iconst_0
 1: istore_1
 2: iload_1
 3: bipush        10
 5: if_icmpge     22
 8: getstatic     #2  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
11: ldc           #3  // String Hello from Hello.main!
13: invokevirtual #4  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
16: iinc          1, 1
19: goto          2
22: return
```

Now my question is why there is 8: getstatic step?

Comment: To understand bytecode, it’s generally helpful to also understand the Java source code. In this specific case, how the statement form `expression.methodName(argument);` applies to `System.out` `println` `(` `"Hello from Hello.main!"` `);`

Answer (score 0):

The `getstatic` instruction loads the value of the static field [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).